# JSON parsing using JSON.NET windows phone

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to parse 7 day forcast from openweathermap. I catch a null reference exeption in the line `foreach (JObject array in JsonRequest["main"]["wind"]["name"]["weather"])`, but I don't understand why. I need to fill my class and show the forcast for 7 days.

```
string queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "?units=metric";
        dynamic results = await DataService.getDataFromService(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);

        MyWeather wetherobject = new MyWeather();
        PanoramaItemObject ItemObject = new PanoramaItemObject();

        var JsonRequest = JObject.Parse(results);

        foreach (JObject array in JsonRequest["main"]["wind"]["name"]["weather"])
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(array.ToString());
            wetherobject.Temperature=(string)obj["temp"];
            wetherobject.Humidity=(string)obj["humidity"];
            wetherobject.Temperature_max=(string)obj["temp_max"];
            wetherobject.Temperature_min=(string)obj["temp_min"];
            wetherobject.Title=(string)obj["main"];
            wetherobject.Description=(string)obj["description"];
            wetherobject.Wind=(string)obj["speed"];
            ItemObject.forecasts.Add(wetherobject);
        }
```

The hierarchy is following:

```
    public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int population { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
    public double pressure { get; set; }
    public double sea_level { get; set; }
    public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_kf { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public string pod { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
    public double __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public string dt_txt { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public City city { get; set; }
    public int cnt { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public List<List> list { get; set; }
}
```

I've done like it was advised. The exeption is: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'list'

```
string queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "?units=metric";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string results = await client.GetStringAsync(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);
        MyWeather wetherobject = new MyWeather();
        PanoramaItemObject ItemObject = new PanoramaItemObject();

        dynamic JsonRequest = JObject.Parse(results);

        foreach (var array in JsonRequest.list)
        {
            //JObject obj = JObject.Parse(array.ToString());
            wetherobject.Temperature=(string)array.main.temp;
            wetherobject.Humidity=(string)array.main.humidity;
            wetherobject.Temperature_max=(string)array.main.temp_max;
            wetherobject.Temperature_min = (string)array.main.temp_min;
            wetherobject.Title=(string)array.weather.main;
            wetherobject.Description=(string)array.weather.description;
            wetherobject.Wind=(string)array.wind.speed;
            ItemObject.forecasts.Add(wetherobject);

        }
```

Comment: Your object hierarchy is not like `main.wind.name.weather`. Paste your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and see the result. (You can also use JsonViewer https://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Agree with what EZI said.  Also try posting to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to visualize your data.  Incidentally, when querying a long sequence of properties when some intermediate properties might be missing, I suggest using [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) since it will return an empty enumerable rather than throwing a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your object hierarchy is different. Example below should work

```
double latitude = 51.5085300;
double longitude = -0.1257400;
string queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/forecast/city?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "?units=metric";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string results = await client.GetStringAsync(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);

dynamic jobj = JObject.Parse(results);
foreach (var item in jobj.list)
{

    Console.WriteLine("{0} TEMP:{1} WIND:{2}", 
        DateTime.ParseExact((string)item.dt_txt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null), 
        (item.main.temp - 273.15), 
        item.wind.speed);
}
```

Comment: dynamic JsonRequest = JObject.Parse(results);
 foreach (var array in JsonRequest.list)

Now I get error 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'list'

Comment: @Youhy I posted a tested working code. See what you do differently.

Comment: Could you write your exaple using  wetherobject.Temperature as an output, not console

Comment: I've posted my new code, I don't understand what's wrong